# How do I make the background inside an icon transparent but not the box around it?

Tags: css, icons, transparency, background-color

When I set the below icon to `background:white` it sets the box around it as well, but what I want is only the background inside the circle to be white but the box around it to still be transparent.

[image]

Comment: for this specific case, did you try border-radius? It will only works on circles, but works

Answer (score 1):

something like:

```
background: white; 
-moz-border-radius: 70px; 
-webkit-border-radius: 70px; 
border-radius: 70px;
```

Adjust the size accordingly